# How to cut grooves in a rectangle

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces

I need to cut some grooves into a flat surface. I have watched tutorials with cylinders, where they extruded faces inward to create the required effect, but rectangles only have six faces, so extruding one of them would accomplish just as much as simply resizing the object. How do you divide a rectangle's face into a grid of extrude-able squares?

Comment: There is of course the Boolean modifier, you could try that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the face where you want to add the groove. Press <kbd>I</kbd> to inset a new face. Then scale it with <kbd>S</kbd> and constrain to a axis (for me it was the X axis), press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude the groove.
[image: animated gif]

Or if you want the groove running all the way across the side, add two loop cuts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>. Then push them closer, by scaling same as above. After you have it the size you want, select the two outside faces and <kbd>E</kbd> extrude them out.

[image: animated gif]

Comment: Thanks for the help on this. Could you make the groove carry on through another, separate object?

Comment: @SnoopDugg12 what do you mean? if you want a groove in multiple objects you should look in to a [boolean modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/generate/booleans.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a boolean modifier.

Create an object that has the shape of the groove you want.

[image]

Then select your original object and add a boolean modifier on difference mode, on the object select the cut object like this:

[image]