# How to make sunken grooves?

Tags: mesh, extrude

I know this seems like a rudimentary question, but I can't seem to depress faces and vertices to look like they do in the picture.  Here is what I am trying to model:

[image]

Here is my screenshot of the cartridge so far:

[image]

Every time I try to extrude, it makes weird distortions and just looks so crude compared to the uniform look of the original picture. How can I do this without causing these problems?  Keep in mind I want this to remain solid, so hopefully that isn't complicating things :)

Here is the .blend [image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27619/how-to-cut-grooves-in-a-rectangle and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67645/how-can-i-make-a-groove-in-a-sphere and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50118/cutting-a-channel-halfway-into-a-shape and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46284/whats-the-most-elegant-way-to-cut-shapes-out-of-a-mesh/46293#46293

Comment: great! If there is one link that can works best please mark your question as a duplicate, or feel free to write an answer with your solution.

Comment: How do I mark as duplicate?

Comment: you can use the close link (between edit and flag) and choose to mark as duplicate.